# I get such an error when I run. ASP.Net 6.0 in program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, .net-6.0

**My line of code that gives errors and builds:**
 `var app = builder.Build();`

**My ApplicationServiceRegister class:**

```
 public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(AuthorizationBehavior<,>));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(CachingBehavior<,>));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(CacheRemovingBehavior<,>));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestValidationBehavior<,>));

            
            services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthManager>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserManager>();

            services.AddSingleton<LoggerServiceBase, FileLogger>();

            return services;
        }
```

**Error Output:**

System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Application.Feature.Auths.Commands.Register.RegisterCommand,Application.Feature.Auths.Dtos.RegisteredDto] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Application.Feature.Auths.Commands.Register.RegisterCommand+RegisterCommandHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'Core.Security.JWT.TokenOptions' while attempting to activate 'Application.Service.AuthService.AuthManager'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2

I dwelt on the possibility of a bug with Dependency Injection, but I didn't see a problem.

Comment: Before suspecting a bug in battle tested frameworks like .NET, make sure you understand the error and verify your own code first. That's far more likely to be the problem. In this case the error is telling you it can't create an AuthManager because it has a dependency on TokenOptions that can't be resolved. Where have you registered a TokenOptions with the DI container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AuthManager` probably requires a parameter in the constructor `TokenOptions`, which is not registered.

If you want to make this work you also have to register the `TokenOptions` in the DI, before adding the `AuthManager` to the DI.

```cs
var options = new TokenOptions(...);
services.AddSingleton(typeof(TokenOptions), options);
```

Comment: Yes you are right I missed it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Like @rotgers said you are probably missing some constructor parameter that the `AuthManager` is expecting. You need to register said parameter in the services container so it is available for `AuthManager`.

Comment: Add more details, like steps or method to implement